# For-loop returns same character in parsing

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, for-loop, parentheses

I am creating a program that will split parentheses for 'separate pairs'. For example `()()` turns into `|()|()|` but `(())` stays the same, being `|(())|`. It keeps 'getting' the same character. I have tried changing **where I insert**, like `pos - 1`, but it still doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
def insert(source_str, insert_str, pos):
        return source_str[:pos]+insert_str+source_str[pos:]


x = 0 
rightSideOfEquation = "()bx((x))c(y(c+1)(x)y)"


for pos in range(len(rightSideOfEquation)):
    if x == 0:
        rightSideOfEquation = insert(rightSideOfEquation,'|',pos)
    if rightSideOfEquation[pos] == '(':
        x += 1
    if rightSideOfEquation[pos] == ')':
        x -= 1

print(rightSideOfEquation)
```

It prints `|||||||||||||||||||||||()bx((x))c(y(c+1)(x)y)`
I want it to print `|()|bx|((x))|c|(y(c+1)(x)y)|`

**NOTE: You can see it here:
**https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1682322/recursive-parsing-parenthesis-with-explanation**
**I have tried changing it to `pos + 1` and `pos -1` with little effect, other than where it is repeating.

Comment: if it's recursive parsing where is your recursion?

Comment: x never stops being 0

Comment: Well, I don't know how to explain it, ill just say you can read more here :)

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to iterate over an iterable's indices while mutating the object (or, in this case, reassigning its reference).

Comment: Any better ways are greatly appreciated, if you can think of it!

Comment: Do you want a `|` after every close `)` or only between `)` and `(`?

Comment: only between `) (` , see my link

Comment: Your link doesn't show any `|`s at all; the examples in your question show `|`s before and after 0-level parens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a "while" statement instead of a for-loop will make your life easier in this case:

```
def insert(source_str, insert_str, pos):
    return source_str[:pos]+insert_str+source_str[pos:]

x = 0 
rightSideOfEquation = "a()bx((x))c(y(c+1)(x)y)"
pos = 0

while pos < len(rightSideOfEquation):
  if rightSideOfEquation[pos] == '(':
      if x==0:        
          rightSideOfEquation = insert(rightSideOfEquation,'|',pos)
          pos+=1
      x += 1
  elif rightSideOfEquation[pos] == ')':
      x -= 1
      if x == 0:
          rightSideOfEquation = insert(rightSideOfEquation,'|',pos + 1)
  pos+=1

print(rightSideOfEquation)
```

This will print the following:

```
a|()|bx|((x))|c|(y(c+1)(x)y)|
```

Although this will be much cleaner and easier using a recursive function, I wanted to show you how you can fix the bug in your existing code instead of completely changing your thought process...

Comment: Recursive function explain please ... Would like code to be as clean as possible!!

Comment: Chosen becuase doesn't involve copies of an object

Answer (score 1):

Modifying an object while you are iterating through it always a recipe for disaster.

You need to build up a new object while you iterate through the old one:

```
equation = "a()bx((x))c(y(c+1)(x)y)"
new_equation = []
parens = 0
for ch in equation:
    if ch == '(':
        if parens == 0:
            new_equation.append('|')
        new_equation.append(ch)
        parens += 1
    elif ch == ')':
        new_equation.append(ch)
        parens -= 1
        if parens == 0:
            new_equation.append('|')
    else:
        new_equation.append(ch)
equation = ''.join(new_equation)
print(equation)
```

Which gives:

```
a|()|bx|((x))|c|(y(c+1)(x)y)|
```

Comment: While this fixed the "|"s that were being printed at the beginning, it is still not correct (notice the extra "|" at the beginning and the missing "|" after "bx" and the first "c").

Comment: @bbkglb:  Yup, it was hard to toll from the OP's requirements, but I suspect you are correct.  Oh, fixed my code to match those results.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to change things that You are iterating over. I have fixed Your code by creating a copy of the input string and it seems to be working:

```
def insert(source_str, insert_str, pos):
    return source_str[:pos]+insert_str+source_str[pos:]


x = 0 
rightSideOfEquation = "a()bx((x))c(y(c+1)(x)y)"
copy = rightSideOfEquation
posincopy = 0

for pos in range(len(rightSideOfEquation)):
    if rightSideOfEquation[pos] == '(':
        x += 1
        if x == 1:
            copy = insert(copy,'|',posincopy)
            posincopy = posincopy + 1
    if rightSideOfEquation[pos] == ')':
        x -= 1
        if x == 0:
            copy = insert(copy,'|',posincopy + 1)
            posincopy = posincopy + 1
    posincopy = posincopy + 1

print(copy)
```

output:

```
a|()|bx|((x))|c|(y(c+1)(x)y)|
```

Comment: Your code does not give the output you've included here. The output from your code is: `|a|()|b|x|((x))|c|(y(c+1)(x)y)` (notice the missing "|" at the end). Plus you are printing an extra "|" at the beginning.

Comment: I have just fixed that.

Comment: But now it is printing `|a|()|b|x|((x))|c|(y(c+1)(x)y)|` which has multiple extra "|"s that shouldn't be there...